# Why can't I defer sending a message for a one-way client

Tags: rebus

What is the rationale behind the following exception when trying to Defer the sending of a message on a one-way client:
    System.InvalidOperationException "Cannot use ourselves as timeout manager because we're a one-way client"

Answer (score 2):

A one-way client is a Rebus client that is not capable of receiving messages, so it has no input queue.

The way `await bus.Defer(...)` works, is by sending a message with [some special headers](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Messages/Headers.cs#L74-L82) to a "timeout manager", which by default is the endpoint that defers the message.

But since a one-way client has no input queue, it has no place to send the deferred message to.

You can make a one-way client defer messages by configuring an external timeout manager like this:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Options(o => o.UseExternalTimeoutManager(anotherQueue))
    .Start();
```

which will then cause the client to send the deferred message to that queue.

*Moreover*, you would have to manually set the [`rbs2-defer-recipient`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Messages/Headers.cs#L79-L82) header to some other input queue, so that the timeout manager knows where to send the message when it is time to be consumed(*).

I hope that explains it :) please let me know if it is not clear.

---

*) This is actually not the case with Rebus 4, because `bus.Defer` uses the normal endpoint mappings to route messages.

Answer (score 1):

If `Rebus.AzureServiceBus` is used there is more simple (or hacky) way to send delayed messages.

You have to specify 2 headers: `rbs2-deferred-until` and `rbs2-defer-recipient` and call `Publish` method like in the example.

```cs
var deferredUntil = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
headers.Add(Headers.DeferredUntil, deferredUntil.ToString("O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
headers.Add(Headers.DeferredRecipient, @"Rebus requires this ¯\_(ツ)_/¯");
await bus.Publish(new SomeMessage(), headers);
```

*Note:* `rbs2-defer-recipient` is required by `Rebus` so any dummy values are okay.

Be careful, it looks like a workaround so it may not work after `Rebus.AzureServiceBus` update. It works for me in [5.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rebus.AzureServiceBus/5.0.1).